# Problemas na passagem de argumentos por parametro

Tags: c

Estou com problemas na passagem de argumentos por parametro. 
O erro ocorre na **linha 23 coluna 5** e é o seguinte:

> too few arguments to function 'imc'

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <unistd.h>

float imc(float tam, float pes);

int main()
{
    float altura;
    float peso;
    float resultado;

    printf("digite a sua altura ");
    scanf("%f",&altura);
    printf("\n\ndigite seu peso ");
    scanf("%f", &peso);

    imc(altura,peso);

    system("clear");

    printf("%f", imc(resultado));

    return 0;
}

float imc(float tam, float pes)
{

    return tam*pow(pes,2);
}
```

Comment: vlw pela edição

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se reparares a tua função `imc` está a pedir dois parâmetros: `float imc(float tam, float pes)`.

No teu `printf` tens `printf("%f", imc(resultado));`, ou seja, a parir do momento que estás a enviar um parâmetro (`resultado`), vai dar erro de parametros.

Para tal não acontecer faz:

```
resultado = imc(altura,peso);

system("clear");

printf("%f", resultado);
```

Comment: aaa vlw, tenho que melhorar o modo como escrevo =P
vou deixar assim `printf("%f", resultado=imc(altura, peso));`

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na chamada da função,

```
float imc(float tam, float pes)
```

Porque na **linha 23** a função `imc` pede **dois argumentos** e só estás a passar um.